# How to build a REGEX pattern to verify an input field

Tags: regex

I have an input search field that I need to edit with Regex, which I am terrible with.  The field can be 1 to 6 characters.  The first three characters, if provided, must be uppercase letters, the second three must be numeric.  So the pattern I have is `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}`, which appears to be working for all 6 characters.  The kicker is at any point the user can end the string with an asterisk.  So "ABC123" is fine.  So is "AB*" or "ABC1*".  "AB1*" is an error. And asterisk by itself is also not allowed.

I tried `[A-Z*]{1-3}[0-9*]{0,3}` but that allows "A**" and "AB1".

What do I need to do?

Comment: `I need to edit with Regex, which I am terrible with` -> http://regexr.com is your friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to describe all possible strings, as an alternation of these sub-patterns :

- `[A-Z]\*`
- `[A-Z]{2}\*`
- `[A-Z]{3}\*`
- `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]\*`
- `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}\*`
- `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}`

With simple factorization you can reduce it to these sub-patterns :

- `[A-Z]{1,3}\*`
- `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,2}\*`
- `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}`

Which gives us this final result : `[A-Z]{1,3}\*|[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,2}\*|[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}`.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks!  I would NEVER have put that together.